# Template parameter pack can't infer `const&` argument

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

So I have a class:

```
struct C {
  int x[10];

  int const& get(int i) const { return x[i]; }

  template<typename... Ts>
  auto& get(Ts... args) {
    int const& (C::*f)(Ts...) const = &C::get;
    return const_cast<int&>((this->*f)(args...));
  }
};
```

and the template will generate a non-`const` getter on demand, so this becomes legal:

```
int& test(C& c) {
  int i = 4;
  int& r = c.get(i);
  return r;
}
```

but if I change the original getter's argument type to a reference:

```
  int const& get(int const& i) const { return x[i]; }
```

the non-`const` getter template can't match the `const` getter anymore.

Obviously it's no big deal passing an `int` by value, and it's no big deal passing the argument list explicitly to the template, but I have more complex arguments and numerous overloads, and I'd like to infer all my non-`const` getters with a minimum of copy-paste.

Is there any way past this?

---

One thought I had was that I could declare the problem argument list within the class but leave the definition to the template, so that the argument matching would have some guidance.  I tried adding the following to the class (either before or after the template):

```
  int& get(int const& i);
```

Unfortunately this bypasses the template altogether and results in a link error.  Adding `inline` or `template` to the declaration didn't seem to do the trick either.

Comment: By "numerous overloads" it turns out I actually have two, but it's the _principle_ I care about.  I might get more later.

Comment: I think your compiler should have complained about `int& i = c.get(i)` as well since `int&` is not const.

Comment: @Anders K., that's why the template exists.  It creates a non-const getter by calling the const getter and stripping const from the result.  This is useful for using the same getter from various const and non-const methods.  If many overloads exist then it picks the one with the matching argument list to the call.  Unfortunately "matching" fails if the const getter takes a reference argument, because the call looks like a by-value call.

Comment: @AndersK., edited for clarity.

Comment: `int const& (C::*f)(std::add_const_t<Ts>&...) const = &C::get;` is this what you want ?

Comment: Why do you need `f` the intermediate variable? Why not call `get` directly?

Comment: @n.m., you're right, I don't need to in this version.  I oversimplified my reduced test case.  I'd experimented with making it more terse for multiple getters by taking a function pointer argument and calling through that.

Comment: I've made a [second attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41160125/2417578) at asking the question I _meant_ to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you enforce the call to a `const` member function through an auxiliary pointer to member-function? In such cases I use `const` qualification of `this`:

```
template<typename... Ts>
auto& get(Ts... args) {
    const C* const const_this = this;
    return const_cast<int&>(const_this->get(args...));
}
```

Comment: Oh, oops!  Because it had evolved from another template where I was trying to get an implicit match on the return type.

Comment: That does make the code work (so it's answered my question); but I'm not so clear on why.  An alternate version, which takes a function pointer argument so that most of the verbiage can be applied to various getters, is still affected.