# How do I get a template parameter pack to infer pass-by-reference rather than pass-by-value?

Tags: c++, c++14, pass-by-reference, variadic-templates

In the following class, `wrapper` takes a pointer to an arbitrary `const` method and returns the result of a call to that method with `const` removed.  This can be used to generate the corresponding non-`const` method...

```
struct C {
  int x[10];

  int const& get(int i) const { return x[i]; }
  int const& getr(int const& i) const { return x[i]; }

  template<typename T, typename... Ts>
  auto& wrapper(T const& (C::*f)(Ts...) const, Ts... args) {
    return const_cast<T&>((this->*f)(args...));
  }

  int& get(int i) { return wrapper(&C::get, i); }
  int& getr(int const& i) { return wrapper(&C::getr, i); }
};
```

almost.

The problem is that the final method `getr()` cannot be compiled, because the argument list passed to `wrapper()` doesn't imply pass-by-reference.  By the time we get inside `wrapper()` the compiler is looking for a pass-by-value version of `getr()`.

Is there a trick to this?

Comment: *Why* are you passing the index by reference? I simply fail to see the reasoning behind it.

Comment: On a similar note (and guessing that the code you show is just a simplified version of some actual code) why have the `const` function return *references*? *If* you're not doing anything more advanced with the wrapper and return types, then returning `const&` is not really useful here. And using a wrapper such as this is also making the code more opaque and unmaintainable.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, some uses of the getter initialise a local reference which they will modify in the context of their work, while other uses of the getter are inside const methods.  I could return a pointer, but it works as a reference and I get the never-`NULL` contract.  The _actual_ index is a complex data structure, and would have been noise in the context of the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [perfect forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward) the arguments to the function:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts, typename... Args>
auto& wrapper(T const& (C::*f)(Ts...) const, Args&&... args) {
  return const_cast<T&>((this->*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

This is achieved by making `args` a forwarding reference parameter pack. Note that we need to introduce a new `Args` template parameter pack in order to deduce the arguments correctly.

Comment: Hm.  Seems to be falling down when I overload `get() const` with an alternative argument list (either no arguments, or a different type).  I'll keep fiddling...